# Reading Multiple Dragged-n-Dropped Files

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mountain-lion, nspasteboard, nsdragginginfo

I have a small window inside the main xib (MainMenu.xib) with an **NSImageView** control for an **OS X** application.  This view control has an NSImageView subclass that is supposed to accept files that the user brings (drag n drop).  Since I have no experience in developing a Mac application with Objective-C, I've searched around, checking out some sample projects from Apple, and got some idea.  Well, to make the story short, I've just copied the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168059/drag-drop-nsdraggingdestination-in-cocoa-does-not-work).  It works.  Great...  The following is a concise version.

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

- (NSDragOperation)draggingUpdated:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
}

- (void)draggingExited:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
}

- (BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
    return YES; 
}

- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSURLPboardType]) {
        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pboard];
        NSLog(@"Path: %@", [self convertPath:fileURL]); // <== That's just what I need
    }
    return YES;
}

- (NSString *)convertPath:(NSURL *)url {
    return url.path;
}
```

For now, the drop box only gets file paths one at a time regardless of the number of files the user drags and drops onto the drop box.  So what I would like to know is how to get the application to read all multiple files the user brings.

Thank you,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your performDragOperation: method to this:

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSURLPboardType]) {
        NSArray *urls = [pboard readObjectsForClasses:@[[NSURL class]] options:nil];
        NSLog(@"URLs are: %@", urls); 
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  It works.  It seems that the following topic can help me out, too.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998158/how-do-i-handle-multiple-file-drag-drop-from-finder-in-mac-os-x-10-5?rq=1

Comment: This answer is golden. I was having enormous trouble in receiving more than one NSURL from my pasteboard. I always was limited to one. This fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Swift Style:

```
override func performDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool 
{
    if let board = sender.draggingPasteboard().propertyListForType(NSFilenamesPboardType) as? NSArray 
    {              
        for imagePath in board
        {
            if let path = imagePath as? String
            {
                 println("path: \(path)")
            }
        }                
        return true               
    }
    return false
}
```